# Can we use the Cloud Storage API for typed custom properties?

Tags: file, winapi, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-shell

Using the [Cloud Files API environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine), is it possible to define typed custom properties? The only method I can find is `Windows.Storage.Provider.StorageProviderItemProperties.SetAsync()`. This takes a list of `StorageProviderItemProperty` whose `Value` is `string`.

However, custom properties defined with the [Property Description Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/propdesc-schema-entry) can have types and offer a lot more control.

For instance, "file size" and "dates" get special treatment in the column headers.

[image: Column header popup for date]
[image: Column header popup for filesize]

Comment: You can define custom all the custom Windows Properties you need and register them using PSRegisterPropertySchema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-psregisterpropertyschema (needs admin right). The special treatment you see is defined in the schema. Now, adding these properties in a a view is only possible per file type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers unless you write your own custom namespace extension (that is a whole different story).

Comment: For cloud based placeholder files, you can register a custom property handler with the package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop3-extendedpropertyhandler

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier - your first comment confirms my suspicion: if we want typed properties, we need to define them with the Property Description Schema.

If you move your comment to an answer I can mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can define custom Windows Properties and register them using the [PSRegisterPropertySchema function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-psregisterpropertyschema). Note registration and unregistration needs admin right so is usually done at install/uninstall time.

The "special treatment" you see is defined in the schema.

Now, adding these properties in a a Shell View is only possible per file type as stated here: [Initializing Property Handlers / Before you begin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers#before-you-begin)

> Property handlers are always associated with specific file types;
> thus, if your file format contains properties that require a custom
> property handler, you should always register a unique file name
> extension for each file format.

For cloud based placeholder files, you can register a custom property handler with the package itself using the [desktop3:ExtendedPropertyHandler Xml element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop3-extendedpropertyhandler) in the manifest.

Comment: Do you have any hints related to ExtendedPropertyHandler implementation (cloud based), what interface should it implement?

Comment: @dmitry.s - I've not tested but it should be the same as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers#before-you-begin IPropertytore, IInitializeXXX etc. You can hook QueryInterface and check what is required

Comment: Yes, I tried to declare an empty ExtendedPropertyHandler class that implements ICustomQueryInterface, but GetInterface for ExtendedPropertyHandler manifest entry never gets called. Even so, implementing ICustomQueryInterface on other handlers (for example, CloudFilesContextMenus entry got calls to the GetInterface method).

Comment: @dmitry.s - you should ask another question